# Need to seperate the Code files from the DB

Tags: php, mysql

I need to develop my PHP application into Java now that I have one. Additionally, in order for me to comprehend business logic and functional flow, I must install the PHP project on my desktop. I require assistance to separate the PHP code files from the database, as they are directly linked to it and display 300 GB in their properties.

How to separate db files and code files

Comment: I don't follow your question. How are PHP  files directly linked to the database? Edit question with exact observations.